# Store Text Files as Binary for Faster Read/Write

Tags: julia, binaryfiles

I have a large set of text files that I need to process. The performance is pretty good now, thanks to `pmap()`,  but i'm looking for an additional speed-up. The current bottleneck is parsing strings into floats.

I had the thought of loading my data (pipe delimited text files) and writing them to a binary format. From what I have seen Julia should be able to load my data faster this way. The problem is that I'm having some trouble with the proper way to load my binary data back into Julia after writing it as binary.

Here's some example code I have for loading, parsing and writing to binary:

```
input_file = "/cool/input/file.dat"   ## -- pipe delimited text file of Floats
output_file = "/cool/input/data_binary" 

open(input_file, "r") do in_file
    open(output_file, "w") do out_file
        for line in eachline(in_file)
            split_line = split(line, '|')
            out_float = parse(Float64, split_line[4])
            write(out_file, out_float)
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is that when I load the above file into Julia, I have no idea what the values are:

```
read(output_file)
n-element Array{UInt8,1}:
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x80
 0x16
```

How can I use these binary values as floats in my Julia code? More generally, does it make sense to convert my text file data to binary in this way, if i'm looking for a performance increase?

Comment: just making sure this isn't an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) scenario: is there a highly specific reason you need this particular format, or are you just trying to find an efficient way to save / load preprocessed data to disk for later processing?

Comment: Just trying to find a more efficient way to save/load data. I'll have a look at JLD.jl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `reinterpret` function:

```rb
help?> reinterpret
search: reinterpret

  reinterpret(type, A)

  Change the type-interpretation of a block of memory. For example,
  reinterpret(Float32, UInt32(7)) interprets the 4 bytes corresponding
  to UInt32(7) as a Float32. For arrays, this constructs an array with 
  the same binary data as the given array, but with the specified element
  type.
```

---

Function to write numeric data:

```rb
julia> function write_data{T<:Number}(file_name::String, data::AbstractArray{T})
           open(file_name, "w") do f_out
               for i in data
                   write(f_out, i)
               end
           end
       end
write_data (generic function with 1 method)
```

Random data:

```rb
julia> data = rand(10)
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.986948
 0.616107
 0.504965
 0.673264
 0.0358904
 0.1795
 0.399481
 0.233351
 0.320968
 0.16746
```

Function that reads binary data and reinterprets it to a numeric data type:

```rb
julia> function read_data{T<:Number}(file_name::String, dtype::Type{T})
           open(file_name, "r") do f_in
               reinterpret(dtype, read(f_in))
           end
       end
read_data (generic function with 1 method)
```

Reading the sample data as `Float64`s yields the same array we written:

```rb
julia> read_data("foo.bin", Float64)
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.986948
 0.616107
 0.504965
 0.673264
 0.0358904
 0.1795
 0.399481
 0.233351
 0.320968
 0.16746
```

Reinterpreting as `Float32`, naturally yields twice as much data:

```rb
julia> read_data("foo.bin", Float32)
20-element Array{Float32,1}:
  1.4035f7
  1.87174
 -9.17366f25
  1.77903
 -1.03106f-24
  1.75124
  1.9495f-20
  1.79332
  2.88032f-21
  1.26856
  1.17736f19
  1.5545
 -3.25944f-18
  1.69974
  5.25285f-17
  1.60835
 -3.46489f14
  1.66048
  1.91915f-25
  1.54246
```

Comment: Thanks this is useful.

Comment: A follow-up here. Is it possible to write/read 2-dimensional arrays in binary, 
or can the data only be stored as vectors?

Comment: @JeremyMcNees You can always reshape the resulting vector, but I really think [`JLD`](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl) is the way to go IMO, ie. `using JLD; save("mat.jld", "mat", rand(2,2)); load("mat.jld")["mat"]` will save and then load the `rand(2, 2)` matrix using HDF5.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how much actual speedup I get, but I store a few things using [.h5 format](https://github.com/JuliaIO/HDF5.jl) when I store large collections of variables that are not structured (as opposed to stuff I would store in a relational database / .json file)

Answer (score 2):

The **official** solution / format to "save" data from the workspace of a julia session is the [JLD package](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl).

Think of this as the equivalent of `.mat` files in matlab, or `shelve` in python.

Alternatively, you can use the `serialize` command to serialize data into a file directly (however, read the word of caution in the JLD page).

If you need this specific "homemade" serialization approach you describe in your question for very specific purposes to do with your particular project, then fine. But otherwise, it just sounds like you want to store and access serialized data efficiently in general, so use JLD instead.

Example:

```
### in file "floats.dat"
1.0|2.0|3.0|4.0|5.0|6.0|7.0|8.0|9.0|10.0
```

```
# Using .jld files
julia> using JLD
julia> S = split( chomp( readstring("floats.dat")), '|');
julia> Floats = [parse(Float64, x) for x in S];
julia> save("myFloats.jld","Floats",Floats)
julia> load("myFloats.jld")
Dict{String,Any} with 1 entry:
  "Floats" => [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0]
```

```
# Using serialize / deserialize
julia> S = split( chomp( readstring("floats.dat")), '|');
julia> Floats = [parse(Float64, x) for x in S];
julia> f = open("out.dat", "w"); serialize(f, Floats); close(f);
julia> f = open("out.dat", "r"); show(deserialize(f))
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is probably a better approach that what I'm trying to do. I'll have a look into this package.